# installed dm-tree vs imported tree

Tags: tree

I am using python 3.12.0 with tensorflow 2.16.1 and keras 3.0.5
I've been trying my hands on ML & CNN. To aid my understanding, I copied some sample codes from some sites and, when I try executing them, I keep getting errors which indicate that the tree version I'm using is not the right one.

Two such errors are: 'Module tree does not have the attribute flatten'

and 'Module tree has no attribute map_structure'

I began by doing the following:

(1)  'pip install dm-tree' and dm-tree ver 0.1.8 was successfully installed

(2)  'import tree' from within my program.

My observation is as follows:

The import in (2) does not use the dm-tree in (1) because the system keeps reporting 'Module tree does not have the attribute flatten'. But dm-tree surely contains the attribute 'flatten'.

To confirm that the import in (2) did not use the dm-tree in (1), I did pip uninstall dm-tree, then import tree as in (2) above, and the system still carried out the import without reporting that module tree is missing.

So, what is the sure-proof way of dealing with dm-tree and tree conflict?

How do I ascertain that 'import tree' in my program actually imports from the dm-tree module earlier installed by 'pip install dm-tree'?

Thanks for any assistance.